# Build URL with conditional query parameters

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I have simple url builder like this:

```
prepareUrl : Params -> String
prepareUrl params = 
   Url.crossOrigin "http://someapi.com/"
    ["posts"]
    [ 
    , Url.string "currency" params.currency
    , Url.string "members[0][birthday]" "12.12.1989"
    ]
```

When i receive param like membersCount 2 or 3 etc, i need to "clone" members[] in request like this:

```
params.membersCount = 3

prepareUrl : Params -> String
    prepareUrl params = 
       Url.crossOrigin "http://someapi.com/"
        ["posts"]
        [ 
        , Url.string "currency" params.currency
        , Url.string "members[0][birthday]" "12.12.1989"
        , Url.string "members[1][birthday]" "12.12.1989"
        , Url.string "members[2][birthday]" "12.12.1989"
        ]
```

The date string itself can remain the same, it doesn't matter. How can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the third parameter of `Url.Builder.crossOrigin` takes a list of `QueryParameter` values, you can build a list from `0` to `memberCount` using `List.range`:

```elm
prepareUrl : Params -> String
prepareUrl params = 
   Url.crossOrigin "http://someapi.com/"
    ["posts"]
    (Url.string "currency" params.currency :: birthdayParams params.memberCount)

birthdayParams : Int -> List Url.QueryParameter
birthdayParams memberCount =
    List.range 0 (memberCount - 1)
        |> List.map (\i -> Url.string ("members[" ++ String.fromInt i ++ "][birthday]") "12.12.1989")
```

Comment: That works, but how can i add more query at beginning? Like (Url.string 'param' param, url.string 'param2' param  :: birthdayParams ....)

Comment: The syntax I used [(`::`)](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#(::)) adds a single item to the head of the list. If you want to add more items to the front, you could use [`List.append`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#append) or [`List.concat`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#concat)